# Using NetSh to find an interface name and define it as a variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, networking, netsh

I am working on a program in batch to set a static IP. I am using a hard coded name of `local area network`, but I would like to be able to find the name of the LAN using `netsh interface show interface` and then setting a variable to the interface name.

This is what it looks like when I use my `netsh interface show interface`.

[image: my netsh interface show interface output.]

The script below is what I am using. I really would like to have the `netsh interface ipv4 set address name = %somekindofvariable%` that is pulled from a `netsh` search for a lan adapter, but I am unsure how to set that variable using `netsh`.

I need the help of people who are far better at this than I.

```
@echo off
CLS
:Menu
Echo.
Echo.......................................................................
Echo Press 1, 2, or 3 to Exit. 
echo.......................................................................
echo.
echo 1 - Set IP for HHS
echo 2 - Set IP for City
ech0 3 - Exit
echo.

Set /P M=Type 1, 2, or 3 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO HHS
IF %M%==2 GOTO CITY
IF %M%==3 GOTO EOF

:City
echo Input IP Address
set /P "address=type in address: " 
echo address is: %address%
@echo off
netsh interface IPv4 set Address name="Local Area Connection" static %address% 255.255.128.0 10.10.1.2
echo Set IP
@echo off
netsh interface IPv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static 10.10.1.17 no
echo set dns
netsh interface IPv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" 10.10.1.19 index=2 no
echo Set alternate dns
echo .
echo . 
echo . 
ipconfig /all
GOTO Menu

:HHS
Echo This does not have anything associated with it yet.
GOTO Menu

ipconfig /all
GOTO Menu
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if there is more than one interface showing? and there's more than one of them showing as Connected? For example: `Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection` and `Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection`?

Comment: Try using `for`

Comment: I'm not sure if that was in response to my question @NekoMusume, but if one of them, lets say the LAN, is for the internal network, and the WLAN is for the internet, I don't really think they should both be modified! The OP would therefore need to determine which interface is connecting to whichever network type they require instead of modifying both of them and hoping it's okay!

Comment: I meant a suggestion for the question, not in response to you @Compo, but I completely agree with your comment.

Comment: Try using `for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface ^| find "Local"') do set var=%%i`

Comment: @compo, thank you! I thought about that as well. To be honest, I am unsure how to have it do if there are multiple networks. I suppose what I am doing I only need to change the LAN connection. I don't want to change wireless.

Comment: @nekomusume I really appreciate that solution. I am going to test it, and I will get back to you on how it works. I did mention above to compo that I am only trying to change the LAN connection whether it be named "LAN", "Local Area Network", or "Ethernet". I have been tinkering with a little bit of the batch programming, but I am still very new. I appreciate it, and I will try it :) Thank you!!

Comment: Hence the reason for my comments, you want to use the LAN @Josh, however the output you're getting from [tag:NetSh] doesn't differentiate wired from wireless. The 'Interface Name' will not necessarily contain a string to identify it as LAN or WLAN. You can rename it easily in the GUI, e.g. 'Rename this connection' in 'Network Connections', or via the CLI, e.g.`%__AppDir__%netsh.exe Interface Set Interface Name="Wireless Network Connection" NewName="EDC"`. So you cannot for example, use an exclusion list with the words `Wireless` or `Wi-Fi` or, select those with `Local` or `Area` in their name.

Comment: You make a good point, @Compo. Maybe I am chasing rainbows with what I want to do. It is a shame that I can't just create a new LAN connection name it what I designate and then save it as the default network. I really appreciate all of your help though :) you two rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this potential solution is that the routing table for an internet connection should show a destination of `0.0.0.0` with a mask also of `0.0.0.0`. *It is possible for more than one interface to do that, but much less likely, so it's not perfect, but better than your previous idea.*

```bat
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "IntName="&For /F "Tokens=1,2,4" %%G In (
    '%__APPDIR__%ROUTE.EXE -4 PRINT^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RC:"0.0.0.0\ *0.0.0.0"'
) Do (Set "_=%%I"&For /F Tokens^=1-2Delims^=^" %%J In (
        '%__APPDIR__%cmd.exe /D/V/C "%__APPDIR__%netsh.exe interface IP show config|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe "\" !_:.=\.!""'
    ) Do (Call Set "$=%%_%%"&Set "_=%%K"
        Echo(%%J|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "%%I">NUL&&(Call Set "IntName=%%$%%"&GoTo Next)))
:Next
If Not Defined IntName GoTo :EOF
Set IntName&Pause
```

In this case, the last line is added just for demonstration purposes, *(it should output a variable name with its value string)*, if your code reaches that point, the variable `%IntName%` should contain the 'Interface Name' string you were looking for.

*As a side note, this potential solution doesn't care whether your internet connection is wired or wireless, it tries only to detect internet connected interfaces, (hopefully there's just one).*

Comment: That is one hell of a solution! You are a brilliant individual, my friend.  I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: If it works for you, @Josh, please consider marking the answer as accepted, by clicking on the large grayed out check mark to the left of the answer. _Also keep it to yourself, nobody else will know it except for us ;) !_

Comment: You are the best haha I see you're a well-kept secret though :P I will do some more testing with it, and if I can make it work then you will absolutely and undeniably be crowned the answer king!